# How to make all images flow one direction in wowslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, wowslider

`I` m going to make all images flow to one direction: right or left.
In my website, images flow left now, but the last image flows right to go to first image.
In Detail, all sliders have their id so they are shown from 1 to 4 .
when the 4 image is shown, it needs to show first image, I want to move images in same direction but now, it moves reverse direction to the first image and start sliding again.
please send me good idea to solve it.

## I want to flow all images in one direction`

```
 jQuery("#wowslider-container1").wowSlider({
  
            effect: fade,
            prev: "",
            next: "",
            duration: <?= isset($page_contents->slider_duration) && ($page_contents->slider_duration > 0) ? $page_contents->slider_duration : 2 ?> * 1000,
            delay: <?= isset( $page_contents->slider_delay) && ($page_contents->slider_delay> 0) ? $page_contents->slider_delay: 2  ?> * 1000,
            width: 1560,
            height: 720,
          
            autoPlay: true,
            autoPlayVideo: false,
            playPause: false,
            stopOnHover: false,
            loop: true,
            bullets: 1,
            caption: true,
            captionEffect: "fade",
            controls: true,
            controlsThumb: false,
              onBeforeStep:0,
          
            responsive: 1,
            fullScreen: false,
            gestures: 2,
           direction: 'left',
            images: [
               image1,
               image2,
               ...
            ]
        });
```